# Why doesn't jest support classProperties syntax?

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I have a node program running on `node12` and I don't have `babel` in my project because I don't like compiling the code. When I use `jest: ^24.9.0` to test my code I get this error message:

> Support for the experimental syntax 'classProperties' isn't currently enabled.

Below is the code causes this error. However, it runs very well on `node`. I have searched this error and many people say to configure the babel for that. I don't really want to bring babel to my project. I don'er understand why `jest` doesn't work with the syntax which is supported by `node`?

```
class Server {
  static INTERVAL = 2000;
```

Comment: it's hard to check across _giant_ Jest codebase but I'd assume they are using `babel` under the hood in sake `jest.mock()` to work. if that's true then when you don't install/configure Babel explicitly `jest` still uses it but with default config. Probably filing ticket into their github will bring answers faster.